# Docker-Compose: Unable to connect NodeJS with Mongo & Redis [Connection Refused]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, redis, docker-compose

I am working with 3 Services:

- api-knotain [main api service]
- api-mongo [mongo db for api service]
- api-redis [redis for api service]

The Dockerfile for api-knotain looks as follows

```
FROM node:latest
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

my docker-compose file as such:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api-knotain:
    container_name: api-knotain
    restart: always
    build: ../notify.apiV2/src
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - api-mongo
      - api-redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URI=api-redis
      - REDIS_PORT=32770
      - MONGO_URI=api-mongo
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - RESEED=true
      - NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
  api-mongo: 
    container_name: api-mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-redis:
    container_name: api-redis
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "32770:32770"
```

runnin

- docker-compose build
- docker-compose up

output:

```
api-knotain    | connecting mongo ...: mongodb://api-mongo:27017/notify
api-knotain    | Redis error: Error: Redis connection to api-redis:32770 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:32770
api-knotain    | mongo error:MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [api-mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.3:27017]
api-knotain    | Example app listening on port 7777!
```

neither mongo nor redis can be connected.
I tried the following things:

- use localhost instead of container name
- use different ports
- use expose vs port

always with the same result

note:

- i can connect without issue to both mongo & redis through local cli 'localhost:port'

what am I missing?

Comment: Redis usually listens on port 6379, and you need to use the container-internal port for inter-container communication.  Does changing `REDIS_PORT=6379` (and also the second port in the Redis `ports: ["32770:6379"]`) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like depend_on did not properly work in 3.3 version of docker compose. after updating the version to 3.7 all works perfectly without any changes to the compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably redis and mongo containers start later than you application and therefore your app will not see those. [To counter this you must wait for those services to be ready.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Also [links is a legacy feature of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on). You should use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) to control startup order and [user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/) if you want to isolate your database and redis containers from external network.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api-knotain:
    depends_on:
      - api-mongo
      - api-redis
    container_name: api-knotain
    restart: always
    build: ../notify.apiV2/src
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - api-mongo
      - api-redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URI=api-redis
      - REDIS_PORT=32770
      - MONGO_URI=api-mongo
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - RESEED=true
      - NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
  api-mongo: 
    container_name: api-mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-redis:
    container_name: api-redis
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "32770:32770"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however still running the same issue sadly